# How can I make this python code more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I realize this is an incredibly inefficient way to code this, so I'm hoping someone will have suggestions on a more efficient method.

Essentially I'm trying to create a column ("freq") with values of 0 for NA and "Nothing" objects and 1 otherwise. Sample df:

```
i   obj           freq

0.  Nothing        0
1.  Something      1
2.  NaN            0
3.  Something      1


for i in range(0,len(df)):
  if str(df["obj"].iloc[i]) == "Nothing" or str(df["obj"].iloc[i]) == NaN:
    d["freq"].iloc[i] = 0
  else:
    df["freq"].iloc[i] = 1
```

Comment: @hamid What's a "Switch statement" in Python?

Comment: @Timus Note that [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) introduces Structural Pattern Matching which is very similar to switch/case constructs in other languages

Comment: Although Switch Statement is alternative to if else state but python have not switch functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np.where()

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'obj': {0: 'Nothing', 1: 'Something', 2: np.nan, 3: 'Something'}})

df['freq'] = np.where((df['obj'] == 'Nothing') | (df['obj'].isnull()), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a dataframe is hard to check if works, but it should

```py
indexer = (df['obj'] == 'Nothing') | (df['obj'].astype(str) == 'NaN')
df.loc[indexer, 'freq'] = 0
df.loc[~indexer, 'freq'] = 1
```

Comment: So request that they provide one?

Comment: Sorry! Just provided a sample df

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is not even necessary to use `numpy`:

```
df['freq'] = (~(df.obj.isnull() | (df.obj == 'Nothing'))) * 1
```

Note:

Is it useful to code with '0' and '1'? Can't we stay with the result of the boolean operation keeping the 'False' and True' values?
If it is the case the answer would simply be:

```
df['freq'] = ~(df.obj.isnull() | (df.obj == 'Nothing'))
```